# How to get Asp.Net MVC 3 current project name?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I have an Asp.net MVC 3 project with name of "abc". It shows `http://localhost:23543/abc/....` when debugging run in VS. The url will be `http://hostname/webAppName/abc/...` after publish the project in a virtual folder under the default web site of IIS 7.

However, there is some jQuery ajax call, using `'/scripts/...'`, in a separated **external** js file. The absolute path of `'/scripts/'` will become `...wwwroot/abc/scripts/...` instead of `...wwwroot/webAppName/abc/scripts/...`. I am creating a js function for wrapping the ajax url links.

```js
var fullPath = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme://@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority';
function GetPath(projectName, url) {
    return fullPath + projectName + url;
}
```

In js file: `... url: GetPath('/scripts/...')....`

How to get the project name? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to create the mvc request url

```
var siteRoot = '@Url.Content("~/")';
function GetPath(url) {
    return siteRoot + url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your markup, you can use a site-relative URL that will be translated to the correct form at runtime:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Oh heck, I didn't read carefully enough.  I see you want to use the URL from a separate file.  This won't help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in script what I tend to do is AJAXify existing anchor links or forms which already have the proper url as they were generated using HTML helpers.

So for example with a form (generated using `Html.BeginForm` helper):

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $.ajax(}
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

or with an anchor (generated using `Html.ActionLink` helper):

```
$('#mylink').click(function() {
    $.ajax(}
        url: this.href,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Of course there might be some cases where you need an url other than a link or a form. What I tend to do in those cases is to use HTML5 `data-*` attributes on some DOM element. For example:

```
<div id="foo" data-url="@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")">foo bar</div>
```

and when I needed this url I would simply:

```
var url = $('#foo').data('url');
```

See how we don't need any `GetPath` function. All the urls are already part of our DOM and in the separate javascript file we simply use them.